# Copy a file to new name in same directory using gulp

Tags: gulp, glob

I'm trying to use gulp to copy one file to the same directory with a dfferent name - the file with a different name exists already. In Unix this is simply `cp ./data/file.json.bak ./data/file.json` In gulp it seems much more tricky (I'm on a Windows system).

I've tried:

`gulp.task('restore-json',function(){
    return gulp.src('./data/file.json.bak')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./data/file.json',{overwrite:true}));
});`

If the file exists, I get a `EEXIST` error. If it doesn't, it creates `file.json` as a directory.

I'm assuming this problem is because gulp uses `globbing` and effectively it's treating `src` and `dest` as paths. Do you know the most efficient way I can do this? I suppose a workaround would be to copy the file to a tmp directory and then rename and copy using glob wildcards, but is that the right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument that you pass to `gulp.dest()` is **not a file name**. It is the name of the **directory** that you want all files in your stream to be written to. See the [docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#path).

If you want to rename a file, use the [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename) plugin:

```
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('restore-json',function(){
  return gulp.src('./data/file.json.bak')
    .pipe(rename({extname:''}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./data/'));
});
```

Comment: If I rename the file, am I just renaming the file in the stream and not the original which I want to stay in place?

Comment: Yes, the file is only renamed in the stream. That means you effectively create a copy of the file when it is written to disk by `gulp.dest()`.